# Which datatype should be use for all types of numeric values in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Which datatype in mysql should be used that supports all types of numeric values like :

```
0
999999
-9999
1.3
-1.3
2.322323
09.3656464
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) data type like

```
decimal(20,8)
```

where
`20` is the total number of decimal places a number you store can have and
`8` is the number of decimal places after the `.`

You can adjust these numbers to your requirements.

Comment: thanks but i when inserted record with -10, it ends up like -10.00000000

Answer (score 0):

Considering number of digits in your examples - `DECIMAL(15,7)`

Or, if performance is of concern and exact numerical precision in not of concern (i.e. you dont store money amounts), you can end up with `DOUBLE`

Answer (score 0):

```
0              Int / Double / Text
999999         Int / Double / Text
-9999          Int / Double / Text
1.3            Double / Text
-1.3           Double / Text
2.322323       Double / Text
09.3656464     Text
```

Now I'm new to MySQL but from my understanding, if you want the last one (09.3656464) then it has to be a text value.